# Query on font size in html with given css style

Tags: html, css

Due to character size limit, html code is attached in the [link](https://github.com/shamhub/books/blob/master/firefox2.html) with css [style](https://github.com/shamhub/books/blob/master/A.css)

On launching html, `View1` to `View8` and their subview are displayed in small font size in firefox unlike IE with the `font-size` value inherited to `<th>` && `<td>` tag.

How can this font-size of table elements be resolved?

Comment: If the resulting sizes are different, then the parent elements have different font sizes (e.g. due to different default font sizes in browsers), though it is possible that due to different rounding and rendering technologies, there are minor (pixel-level and subpixel-level) differences. You need to provide code that actually reproduces the problem – a complete minimal document, either with parent font size set in the code or a description of browser font size settings provided.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Sure. will update with font size set in the code.

Comment: You did not provide more information but less—you now removed the font-family setting—and different information—changing the figure from 70% to 75%. You have not provided code that actually reproduces the issue.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela If i set "font-size: 16px" absolute at `<table>` level, it works. But not at `<body>` level. Do you think this is right approach?

Comment: If you set font size to 16px (which is the common default in browsers) either on `body` or on `table`, the cells have a font size of 11.2px if you have set it to 70%. There is no difference between browsers here. So if you have observed something else, then there is something else on your page that makes a difference, probably *other* font size settings. If you test with just the code you have posted here, you won't see a difference. So please post code that *actually* produces the problem you have described verbally.

Comment: You are supposed to post HTML and CSS code that reproduce the problem, instead of posting HTML and CSS code that do *not* reproduce it. Posting a link to hundreds of lines of Java code sounds like a bad joke.

Comment: I did not ask a question. I asked you to provide HTML and CSS in the question itself. So that anyone, including you, can copy that code and see whether it reproduces the problem. The code you have provided does not. And it does not help to edit the question to contain *different* snippets that do not reproduce anything as such.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I uploaded the complete html and css.

Answer (score 2):

In CSS, percent font-sizes are relative to the font-sizes of their parent. Therefore, `th` and `td`'s font sizes will be 70% of the closest parent element with an explicitly or implicitly set font-size. You will need to set a non-relative (no `%`, no `em`s) font-size on either `tr` or some other element that will be a parent of both `tr` and `td`.

Comment: It's valid to set font-size to `%` or `em` or any other measuring unit

Comment: @justinas I am aware of that, what I was referring to is that if OP wants to have a consistent font size across browsers, he will need to override their respective user agent stylesheets' implicit font-sizes on parents of 'td' and 'tr'.

Comment: @overexchange You might need to use a different font size for another table, so I would recommend either setting an id or class on the table(s) that need a different font size and using that as the selector instead of `table`. Wouldn't want to run into weird styling problems down the road.

Comment: I added a new class in css file that mentions `font-size: 16px` and assigned this class to outer most `<td>` tag of `<table>` element of html given in the query, but things does not work, because it gets overridden by other class properties. With the html code given in the above query, not sure where to assign my new class.

Comment: Firstly I could not understand the reason for the small font size for `<table>` elements in forefox unlike iE